# Print WooCommerce products list sorted by SKU

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My client has asked "I would like to be able to print a listing of all products by SKU (sorted alphanumerically) with description, and by description (alpha) with the associated SKU." I think the closest I could get for him is to have the SKU sorted alphanumerically but not both, though I could be wrong.

Looking at this question: [Woocommerce: get a list for all sku product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858431/woocommerce-get-a-list-for-all-sku-product), I wonder if I could build a table instead of a list and pull the description in next to the SKU?

Here's the code I'm thinking of based on the link above (without sorting):

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
query_posts( $args );
if( have_posts() ):
    echo '<table>';
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<tr><td>'. $product->get_sku() . ' - ' . $product->get_title() . '</td><td>' . $product->get_description() . '</td></tr>';
endwhile;
echo '</table>';
endif;
```

I don't think the description is the correct way to call it, but I didn't see one to call in the short description.Also, I'm not sure how I would have it sort by SKU. My PHP knowledge is limited.

Even if that code worked, I'm not sure where I would put it to call this in. Can I make it on an admin page or would it be better to create a regular page and use a different template and put this directly into the PHP of that template file?

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: not too sure about woo commerce, but if it worked for the last question ... id say there is more to the code tho.... but yes if the php vars are filled the above will work. as regards where to place it, place it in a template file if you are only calling this once, if you want to use it repeatly, place it in a separate file and call this when needed.

Comment: It would only need to be used once by the client when he needs to print the list. I guess the main question I have is getting the 'sort' feature added to the above code. I think I can handle getting it into a template no problem. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't directly answering your question, but give Woocommerce Store Exporter plugin a try. https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-exporter/  It allows you to export the products into CSV which can be opened in Excel and then sorting can be applied in Excel.